# Separating Hive storage from Spark cluster (compute layer)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-platform

We have a scenario to use Storage capabilities of Hive (HDFS underneath) and Computing power of Spark cluster in the cloud environment. Is there a way that we can separate the two layers clearly.

Scenario:

1. Hive keeps getting data on regular basis (persistence layer). This
   can't be deleted/removed at wish.
2. Processing the data sitting in Hive layer using Spark cluster at any
   point. But we don't want to keep the cluster infrastructure in idle
   state once computing is finished.

So, we are thinking of having cluster created in cloud just before the processing is needed and delete the spark cluster as soon as the processing is over. Advantage will be in saving cost of keeping the cluster resources .

If we load data onto Hive in one cluster of nodes, then can we read this data for processing in a spark cluster without doing data movement.

Assumption- the datanodes of Hadoop are not using a high end configuration and they are not suitable for doing spark in memory processing (low on CPUs; low on RAM).

Please suggest if this kind of scenario is possible in cloud infrastructure (GCP). Is there a better way to approach this.

Comment: Have you considered building your own cluster on Compute Engine? Setting up Hadoop is easy and well documented. Then you can start and stop, configure apps, etc as to meet your goals.

Comment: Actually- the need is to have cloud infrastructure for storage and compute layers. That's why, this architectural ask of whether we can separate the two in some way to keep a tab on costs.